# cgdb not working macOS Sierra

Tags: gdb, macos-sierra, cgdb

I'm trying to run after setting a breakpoint in `cgdb`

```
Starting program: /path/to/my/executable
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 1996: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
 (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

I tried both these guides with no success:

https://opensource.apple.com/source/lldb/lldb-69/docs/code-signing.txt

https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin

Running macOS Sierra 10.12.2 (16C67)